# enumerateObjectsUsingBlock in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to iterate through an array using enumerateObjectsUsingBlock to fetch data.
How to use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock in Swift ? Please help me with an example.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

## Foundation

`enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` is not a method on Array but on NSArray. If you want to use it you'll need an instance of NSArray rather than Array.

```
import Foundation

var array: NSArray = ["Some", "strings", "in", "an", "array"]

array.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({ object, index, stop in
    //your code
})
```

if you have an existing array, you can cast a swift `Array` to an `NSArray` using `as`

```
var cocoaArray = swiftArray as NSArray
```

or if you simply `import Foundation` the Swift compiler will automatically bridge your Swift array to an NSArray and all the NSArray methods will become available for you.

## Swift 1

or you can just use Swift's `enumerate` function:

```
for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
    // your code
}
```

## Swift 2

In Swift 2, `enumerate` is no longer a free function, now it's in a protocol extension!

```
for (index, value) in array.enumerate() {
    // your code
}
```

## Swift 3

And in Swift 3, `enumerate` was renamed to `enumerated`

```
for (index, value) in array.enumerated() {
    // your code
}
```

Comment: I am using the instance of NSArray only. Please find my code : Here data is NSArray data.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock(block: ((AnyObject!, Int, CMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void)?) is giving error.

Comment: that's because the closure you are passing in isn't valid. Pass it in like I did in my answer.

Comment: What you have there is a closure signature which will not work.

Comment: @Lance This maybe a ignorant question but what is the significance of `in` after `stop`?

Comment: @random `in` separates the arguments from the body in a Swift closure.

Comment: The last statement about `import Foundation` does not seem to be true any more as of Beta6.

Comment: @Mundi good find, I'm wondering if this is intentional or not.

Comment: we should really start using the more Swift like syntax ASAP, i'd prefer the answer below that returns the pair of (idx, object)

Comment: I agree that a native swift function would be better. However, his question specifically asked about calling `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`

Answer (score 9):

The new enumerate function returns a tuple with indexer and value so you can get similar functionality to enumerateObjectsUsingBlock.

```
func myBlock (index: Int, value: Int, inout stop: Bool) -> Void {
    println("Index: \(index) Value: \(value)")
    if index == 3 {
        stop = true
    }
}

var array = [1,2,3,4,5]

for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
    var stop = false;
    myBlock(index, value, &stop)
    if stop  {
        break;
    }
}

//Output...
//Index: 0 Value: 1
//Index: 1 Value: 2
//Index: 2 Value: 3
//Index: 3 Value: 4
```

I imagine they haven't exposed enumerateObjectsUsingBlock as you can replicate the functionality with the above code.

**EDIT:** Anonymous function was crashing my playground so used an inline function.  Also added using stop variable for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Thanks, it gave me the idea to proceed further :)

Comment: Glad I could help.  @Lance is spot on though, if you really want to use the old way you could use an NSArray.

Comment: I prefer this approach, because I find it more readable.  I was able to use an anonymous function without a crash (enumerating over a set), which makes the code quite succinct.

        for (index, value) in enumerate(array) {
            // Do stuff based on value
        }

Answer (score 2):

The existing answers can achieve what has been asked in the question. 
Also, you can write an extension to Array class and add similar method as -

```
extension Array{
func enumerateObject(_ block : (Any, Int,inout Bool)-> Void){
    var stop = false
    for (index, aValue) in self.enumerated(){
        block(aValue,index,&stop);
    }
}
```

//uses

```
let numArr = [2,4,7,8,9];
numArr.enumerateObject { (aValue, index, stop) in
    let value = aValue as! Int
    if !stop{
        print("At index \(index) value \(value)");
    }  
    if value == 7{
        print(value);
        stop = true;    
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I write the extension of CollectionType.

[Any way to stop a block literal in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793880/any-way-to-stop-a-block-literal-in-swift/34787167#34787167)

```
    func forEach(body: ((Self.Generator.Element, Int, inout Bool) -> Void)) {
        var stop = false
        let enumerate = self.enumerate()
        for (index,value) in enumerate {
            if stop { break }
            body(value,index,&stop)
        }
    }
```