# How to stop enumerateObjectsUsingBlock Swift

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, block, swift, enumeration

How do I stop a block enumeration?

```
    myArray.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock( { object, index, stop in
        //how do I stop the enumeration in here??
    })
```

I know in obj-c you do this:

```
    [myArray enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id *myObject, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        *stop = YES;
    }];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [enumerateObjectsUsingBlock in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120115/enumerateobjectsusingblock-in-swift)

Comment: The link basically says, don't use enumerateObjectsUsingBlock in swift, because the functionality is better expressed using `for ... in.. enumerate`

Comment: @David: not a duplicate. the other thread does not cover the stop parameter.

Comment: Yeah it does, the answer deals with how to replace this older call with the newer syntax and how to stop it early as well.

Comment: if we are asked to give an answer regarding a specific api, It might be helpful to give an alternate option but technically it is not an answer. only one opinion. If you are ask in a math exam to calculate some function with Taylor but you use Fourier, because ou think it is better for what reason ever, it is complete failure. if OP needs/wants to use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock`, we shouldn't force him to use something else. though we should mention a better way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Swift 1:

```
stop.withUnsafePointer { p in p.memory = true }
```

In Swift 2:

```
stop.memory = true
```

In Swift 3 - 4:

```
stop.pointee = true
```

Comment: Holy FSM, why is that so difficult to do? I guess because your not suppose to use `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` but `for` crap

Comment: Because they are bridging some of the horrible stuff from Objective-C into Swift

Comment: Because Apple now recommends using `for (index, value) in array.enumerate()` instead, which eliminates the block and the stop entirely, while duplicating exactly the same functionality much more clearly.

Comment: @random. if you can you should use Array, not NSArray and the `for obj in myArray`-Syntax.

Comment: @david: enumerate is a global function, not a method on array. it is called `enumerate(array)`

Comment: @hypercrypt `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock` works like charm in Objective-C though.

Answer (score 37):

This has unfortunately changed every major version of Swift. Here's a breakdown:

**Swift 1**

```
stop.withUnsafePointer { p in p.memory = true }
```

**Swift 2**

```
stop.memory = true
```

**Swift 3**

```
stop.pointee = true
```

Answer (score 20):

since *XCode6 Beta4*, the following way can be used instead:

```
let array: NSArray = // the array with some elements...

array.enumerateObjectsUsingBlock( { (object: AnyObject!, idx: Int, stop: UnsafePointer<ObjCBool>) -> Void in

        // do something with the current element...

        var shouldStop: ObjCBool = // true or false ...
        stop.initialize(shouldStop)

        })
```

Comment: I was about to post an answer that noted that `stop[0] = true` worked, but I think I like `stop.initialize(true)` more. The lack of clear guidance on this topic (for a pattern that is used a lot) is a tad frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer is correct but will work for NSArrays only. Not for the Swift datatype `Array`. If you like you can recreate it with an extension.

```
extension Array{
    func enumerateObjectsUsingBlock(enumerator:(obj:Any, idx:Int, inout stop:Bool)->Void){
        for (i,v) in enumerate(self){
            var stop:Bool = false
            enumerator(obj: v, idx: i,  stop: &stop)
            if stop{
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

call it like

```
[1,2,3,4,5].enumerateObjectsUsingBlock({
    obj, idx, stop in

    let x = (obj as Int) * (obj as Int)
    println("\(x)")

    if obj as Int == 3{
        stop = true
    }
})
```

or for function with a block as the last parameter you can do

```
[1,2,3,4,5].enumerateObjectsUsingBlock(){
    obj, idx, stop in

    let x = (obj as Int) * (obj as Int)
    println("\(x)")

    if obj as Int == 3{
        stop = true
    }
}
```

Comment: it does on my machine. with beta 3.

Comment: @VyachaslavGerchicov I guess your question is: "Why has this been upvoted if it doesn't work". Well, it did 4 years ago. Swift has been undergoing several incompatible changes. Fell free to fix it.

Comment: @vikingosegundo `Cannot assign to value: 'stop' is a 'let' constant`. The simplest solution I found is `stop.initialize(to: true)`. Do you know a better one which works?

Answer (score -3):

Just `stop = true`

Since stop is declared as inout, swift will take care of mapping the indirection for you.

Comment: `Cannot assign 'let' value 'stop'`

Comment: Use `stop.memory = true`