# How to stop enumerating attributes of a NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, swift, nsattributedstring, enumeration

In the documentation of the `enumerateAttribute` method it is said, regarding the `stop` argument of the block, that:

> The block can set the value to true to stop further processing of the set.

However, inside the block the `stop` argument is a `let` and I can't set it to `true`.

I need to stop enumerating after the first attribute occurrence found. How could I do that?

Comment: Closely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214136/how-to-stop-enumerateobjectsusingblock-swift.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The parameter is a reference that holds the actual value:

```
let attributed: NSAttributedString = ...

attributed.enumerateAttribute(
    NSFontAttributeName,
    in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributed.length),
    options: []
) { value, range, stop in
    stop.pointee = true
}
```

See the reference for [UnsafeMutablePointer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafemutablepointer).