# Set stop variable in enumerateAttributes block

Tags: ios, swift

For some reason, I"m not able to set the `stop` parameter in `NSAttributedString`'s `enumerateAttributes(in:options:using:)` function. Here's my code:

```
attributedText.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: self.text?.characters.count ?? 0), options: []) {
       (attributes, _, stop) in

       var clearTypography = false
       for (key, _) in attributes {
            // If either font or textColor are set on the label,
            // update both and break out. The attributedText
            // will override the relevant properties once we set
            // it
            if key == NSFontAttributeName || key == NSForegroundColorAttributeName {
                clearTypography = true
                stop = true
                break
            }
        }
```

However, on the line where I'm setting `stop = true` I get the error `Cannot assign to value: 'stop' is a 'let' constant`. I've tried `stop.memory = true` to get the same error.

Any idea why I'm not able to assign to the variable? It's stated purpose is to stop the enumeration when it's assigned to `true`, so I have to imaging I'm just missing something here.

Comment: I am sure there is a duplicate question but I can't find it now.

Comment: `stop.pointee = true`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24214136/how-to-stop-enumerateobjectsusingblock-swift and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41547030/how-to-stop-enumerating-attributes-of-a-nsattributedstring

Comment: `stop.memory = true` seems to be Swift2.