# Any way to stop a block literal in swift

Tags: swift

Like below, i want to stop the literal by something like `break`

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4]
numbers.forEach {
    if $0 % 2 == 0 {
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Comment: Just an example here, i just want to control the flow.

Comment: I solved. See  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33793880/any-way-to-stop-a-block-literal-in-swift/34787167#34787167

Comment: You could also throw an exception

Comment: If you are just trying to check all numbers, you could use .allSatisfy or .contains(where: on the array.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

`forEach` is not a loop (it is a block passed to a loop, but not a loop itself), or more accurately, `forEach` is not part of Swift's **Control Flow**.  Which is why you can't use `break` or `continue`.

**Just use a for-in loop.**

---

**Example :**

```
var numbers = [ 1,2,3,4]

func firstEvenNumber(inArray array: [Int]) -> Int? {

    var firstMatch : Int?

    for number in numbers {
        if (number % 2) == 0 {
            firstMatch = number
            break
        }
    }
    return firstMatch
}

firstEvenNumber(inArray: numbers) // 2
```

---

You can use `return` inside the `forEach` closure, but it does not *break* the loop, it only *returns* the block in the current pass.

```
var numbers = [ 1,2,3,4]

func evenNumbers(inArray: [Int]) -> [Int] {

    var matches : [Int] = []

    numbers.forEach{
        if $0 % 2 == 0 {
            matches.append($0)

            // early return on even numbers
            // does not stop forEach
            // comparable to a continue in a for in loop
            return
        }

        // only reached on uneven numbers
    }
    return matches
}

evenNumbers(numbers) // [2,4]
```

Comment: actually, in 2nd example 'return' does nothing. Remove it and result will be same. To see how it work in foreach, try this:     inArray.forEach{
        if $0 % 2 != 0 {
            return
        }
        matches.append($0)
    }

Comment: @Aleksandr that is exactly the point. `return` is available inside `forEach` but doesn't have the wanted effect of the OP.

Comment: So use: [y enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id x, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop){}];   :)

Comment: The point of my answer was not to provide a hacky work around, there are many. I tried to explain why it wasn't working the way the OP expected it too and to provide an idiomatic way to achieve the wanted result.

Comment: Sure, I understand. Last was just a joke. But I noticed that ur code shows only that return doesn't work as expect ( OP btw doesn't expect using return for it), it doesn't show HOW it works. Return in example does nothing. it returns from iteration that anyway will be "ended" after it. I don't want argue or chat, have a nice day.

Comment: About @ZaporozhchenkoAleksandr 's comment. You're right that it doesn't have the OP's effect. But for that single *iteration*, it does exit early. It works more like a `continue`. You might want to make an edit to clarify that

Comment: @Honey updated with a few comments. Hope that it clarifies the code.

Answer (score 22):

Actually, the best way to do this is kinda:

```
numbers.first { (number) -> Bool in
    return number % 2 == 0
}
```

If u want the only first number, sure. As I understand from the question, that's what u need 'break' for.

If u need all numbers, use:

```
numbers.filter { $0 % 2 == 0 }
```

Answer (score 10):

The document has explained。

```
    /// - Note: You cannot use the `break` or `continue` statement to exit the
    ///   current call of the `body` closure or skip subsequent calls.
    /// - Note: Using the `return` statement in the `body` closure will only
    ///   exit from the current call to `body`, not any outer scope, and won't
    ///   skip subsequent calls.
```

But you would like to try this.

```
extension CollectionType {

    /// Use as
    ///
    ///      let num = [1,2,3,4,5]
    ///      num.forEach{
    ///        if $1 > 3 { $2 = true }
    ///        print($0,$1)
    ///      }
    func forEach(body: ((Self.Generator.Element, Int, inout Bool) -> Void)) {
        var stop = false
        let enumerate = self.enumerate()
        for (index,value) in enumerate {
            if stop { break }
            body(value,index,&stop)
        }
    }

    /// Use as
    ///
    ///      let num = [1,2,3,4,5]
    ///      num.forEach{
    ///        if $0 > 3 { $1 = true }
    ///        print($0)
    ///      }
    func forEach(body: ((Self.Generator.Element, inout Bool) -> Void)) {
        var stop = false
        for value in self {
            if stop { break }
            body(value,&stop)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose in your case the most convenience is:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4]
for (_, element) in numbers.enumerated() {
    if element % 2 == 0 {
        break
    }
}
```